# Should I initialize a member variable in declaration when it is initialized by a constructor parameter?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, initialization

Which is recommended for initialization of class fields in C#:

```
class Foo
{
    public X x = new X(); // or any default value...
    public Foo(X _x)
    {
       x = _x;
    }
}
```

Or

```
class Foo
{
    public X x;
    public Foo(X _x)
    {
       x = _x;
    }
}
```

Please note in the second version, it is probable that I introduce other constructors where `x` may not be initialized!

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: @gnat I edited it to point the language

Comment: In the C# coding standards where I work there is a note saying that direct initializations of a field may cause the debugger to skip around while debugging the instantiation of a class. This might be something to consider. (I've not tested this myself.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should choose between init in declaration or constructor, not both.

In a language that has a default constructor where you don't have to explicitly provide a constructor if the default is all you need, a declaration init may be fine. As soon as you need an explicit constructor with parameter, I tend to move everything to constructor(s), to ensure that init behaviour is in one place.

Too be honest, I hardly ever use declaration init, but that may just be preference. My perceived advantage is that all init behaviour is always encapsulated in constructors: I never have to look in two places (or miss it up in the variable declaration).

Re:

> "it is probable that I introduce other constructors where x may not be initialized"

You should always code constructors to re-use another constructor as appropriate. E.g. in your example, adding another constructor with additional param could be done like this:

```java
class Foo
{
    public X x;
    public Y y;

    public Foo(X _x)
    {
       x = _x ?? new X();
    }

    //WRONG!
    public Foo(X _x, Y _y)
    {
       x = _x;
       y = _y;
    }

    //Right
    public Foo(X _x, Y _y)
    {
       this(_x);
       y = _y ?? new Y();
    }
}
```

Finally, when delegating to another constructor, always prefer this() to base() (super() in Java) since it adds to local cohesion. For more detail on this() vs base() in C#, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797528/base-and-this-constructors-best-practices

Comment: +1. IMHO it boils down to if you care that the field is null after `Foo` is instantiated. `public X x` - this guy is `public` AND we have a constructor that <strike>does</strike> did not check for `null`. This tells me we don't care. Caveat emptor!